# See tooltip on touch screen devices

Tags: touchscreen

Is there a way to easily see web element tooltip on touch screen devices like iPad or iPhone?

For some elements on site, e.g. tags this can be achieved by taping and then go back in web browser’s history (screen shot from Google Chrome on iPad):

> [image: tag tooltip]

I’m looking for method that works on any elements, as if I use mouse pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such generic method because tooltips are not "native" to the web - they're implemented by web sites using generic means. Not every web site will create them the same way, and as such there's no generic method.

In this case Stackoverflow uses a jQuery-based popup system that attaches to event handlers for the mouse (for example the mouseover event). For touch based systems web pages should take advantage of touch events or similar to provide an alternative to users on touch screen devices.